# NetUserSetInfo:"User name could not be found"

Tags: c++, winapi

I was writing a c++ program that could change the password of a logged user(only one user will exist on that machine) and this program will run as a service on that machine, I found a method `NetUserSetInfo` for doing the job and the reason I chose `NetUserSetInfo` is I don't want to feed the old password, find my code below

```
void chpwd::initialize() // function that initialize params of NetUserSetInfo
{
    cout<<"initializing"<<endl;
    string un=getenv("USERDOMAIN");
    un+="\\";
    un+=getenv("USERNAME"); //"USERDOMAIN\USERNAME", I gave name also,since the target machine won't be in domain
    wstring uname=wstring(un.begin(),un.end());
    wUserName=(wchar_t*)uname.c_str();
    wcout<<wUserName<<endl;
    wComputerName=_wgetenv (L"COMPUTERNAME");
    wcout<<wComputerName<<endl;
    string pw(p.genpassword());
    cout<<"pw "<<pw<<endl;
    wstring pwd=wstring(pw.begin(),pw.end());
    wcout.flush();
    wNewPassword=const_cast<LPWSTR>(pwd.c_str());
    wcout<<wNewPassword<<endl;

}

bool chpwd::chngpwd() //funtion that changes password
{
     initialize();
    do
    {
    pi1003.usri1003_password = wNewPassword;
          wcout.flush();
          wcout<<wNewPassword<<endl;
           nas = NetUserSetInfo(
                   wComputerName,  // computer name
                   wUserName,      // username
                   1003,           // info level
                   (LPBYTE)&pi1003,     // new info
                   NULL
                   );
        if(nas != NERR_Success)
        {
             DisplayErrorText(nas);
             l.logic_log(l.time(),"Error occured while reseting password \n old password \""+p.prevp+"\" retains");
        }
        Sleep(1000);
    }while(nas != NERR_Success);
    return 1;

}
```

when I run the code the params are properly initialized, but I am getting `The username could not be found.` error while changing the password, I don't really get this error, the username I have given is correct and I have also executed the code in some machine that is not under any domain and has admin rights, but still the same, Can anyone point me what went wrong.

```
bool chpwd::chngpwd()
{
    wstring uname = _wgetenv(L"USERDNSDOMAIN");
    uname += L"@";
    uname += _wgetenv(L"USERNAME"); 
    wcout << L"un " << uname << endl;//OP-Rixxxx.com@Richy_G

    wstring cname = _wgetenv (L"COMPUTERNAME");
    wcout << L"cn " << cname << endl;//TExxxxM

    wstring pwd;
    string pw = p.genpassword();//eadjbic3
    int len = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, pw.c_str(), pw.length(), NULL, 0);
    if (len > 0)
    {
        pwd.resize(len);
        MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, pw.c_str(), pw.length(), &pwd[0], len);
    }
    wcout << L"pw " << pwd << endl;
    do
    {
    pi1003.usri1003_password = const_cast<LPWSTR>(pwd.c_str());;
          //wcout.flush();
          //wcout<<wNewPassword<<endl;
           nas = NetUserSetInfo(
                   cname.c_str(),  // computer name
                   uname.c_str(),      // username
                   1003,           // info level
                   (LPBYTE)&pi1003,     // new info
                   NULL
                   );
        if(nas != NERR_Success)
        {
             DisplayErrorText(nas);
             l.logic_log(l.time(),"Error occured while reseting password \n old password \""+p.prevp+"\" retains");
        }
        Sleep(1000);
    }while(nas != NERR_Success);
    return 1;

}
```

> Again the variables are obtained with the proper value but still it
>   says

`user name couldn't be found`

Comment: This is somewhat trial and error test cases, but have you tried setting the computer name to NULL so it uses the local machine (seeing as you mention the service is being installed on the local machine anyway) and have you attempted `NetUserGetInfo` to retrieve any data and come across the same issue?

Comment: You don't show the types of your variables and you don't show the values of your variables. The error code says that your user name is wrong. What do you expect from us now? What shall we guess for you? Have you tested `NetUserSetInfo` with hard coded string literals to eliminate any error during building the parameters for `NetUserSetInfo`?

Comment: You cannot cast a char* to wchar_t*, the user's name will turn into Chinese.  Very easy to see with a debugger btw.  It requires a *conversion*, use mbstowcs() or MultiByteToWideChar().  Or use NetUserSetInfoA().  It will still fail in the rare case where the username contains a Unicode codepoint that cannot be encoded in the current code page.  Use wchar_t consistently.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, the `NetUser...` functions don't accept qualified usernames, either in backslash or in ampersand format.  If this is a local account, try just the bare username.  If this is a domain account, you need to find the name of a domain controller and pass that as the computer name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `wstring(iterator,iterator)` is not the correct way to convert an Ansi-encoded `std::string` to a Unicode `std::wstring`. That will only work correctly for ASCII characters, other characters will not be converted correctly. Use `MultiByteToWideChar()` or equivalent instead, or just use `_wgetenv()` instead of `getenv()`.

But more importantly, you should move all of the `initialize()` code into `chngpwd()` directly and get rid of all the intermediate variables.  You are initializing `wUserName` and `wNewPassword` with data from *local variables* that go out of scope when `initialize()` exits. Thus they are left pointing at invalid memory by the time they are passed to `NetUserSetInfo()`.

Try something more like this:

```
bool chpwd::chngpwd()
{
    wstring uname = _wgetenv(L"USERDOMAIN");
    uname += L"\\";
    uname += _wgetenv(L"USERNAME");
    wcout << L"un " << uname << endl;

    wstring cname = _wgetenv (L"COMPUTERNAME");
    wcout << L"cn " << cname << endl;

    wstring pwd;
    string pw = p.genpassword();
    int len = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, pw.c_str(), pw.length(), NULL, 0);
    if (len > 0)
    {
        pwd.resize(len);
        MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, pw.c_str(), pw.length(), &pwd[0], len);
    }
    wcout << L"pw " << pwd << endl;

    USER_INFO_1003 pi1003;
    pi1003.usri1003_password = const_cast<LPWSTR>(pwd.c_str());

    NET_API_STATUS nas;
    do
    {
        nas = NetUserSetInfoW(
                   cname.c_str(),  // computer name
                   uname.c_str(),      // username
                   1003,           // info level
                   (LPBYTE)&pi1003,     // new info
                   NULL
        );
        if (nas == NERR_Success) break;
        DisplayErrorText(nas);
        l.logic_log(l.time(), "Error occured while reseting password \n old password \"" + p.prevp + "\" retains");
        Sleep(1000);
    }
    while (true);
    return 1;
}
```